# Add dynamic property to type alias with known properties

Tags: typescript

I want to define a type alias like this:

```
export type Context = object & {
    tag: string
}
```

When using the type, I also want to be able to add properties dynamically like this:

const context: Context = {
    tag: 'some-tag',
    dynamicProperty: 1
}

I'm getting this error (which I fully understand):

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and
>   'dynamicProperty' does not exist in type 'Context'.

Is there a way to allow dynamically added properties anyway?

I tried this

```
export type Context = any & {
    tag: string
}
```

But then this would be valid from the TS compilers perspective:

```
const context: Context = {
    //tag: 'some-tag', // tag is not set which shouldn't be allowed
    dynamicProperty: 1
}
```

[TS Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2NTwLxwDeAUHGQgIYDmAXHAM4xQCWmVxAvscQMZaNw+2XHQzCQ+IqXIxqdAOT0IAW2ABaWVXkAaaWQAmiTBWXMeABSgQUsRAoCMAJgDM8zkA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a index signature to the type declaration of `Context` to allow more key value pairs:

```
export type Context = {
    tag: string,
    [k: string]: any;
}
```

[TS Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2NTwLxwDeAUHGQgIYDmAXHAM4xQCWmVANKeQNoDWdjFmwC6dCpkQBuYgF9ixAMZZGcJdlx0M6kPiJcyManQDk9CAFtgAWkNVjncnAAmiTBXPMFABSgQUsRBMARgAmAGZjWSA)